# client server android app

Tags: android, tomcat

i have developed an android application in android sdk 2.2 . This app is having tomcat server connectivity as well as mysql database connectivity. this app is running fine on emulator.
but for deploying this app on android device do i need to configure any settting??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access dev machine localhost via usb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524444/access-dev-machine-localhost-via-usb)

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly, if you have it working in an emulator. But why ask this on StackOverflow? Just go out and try it on a device. Also be aware that client network connectivity is frequently slow, error-prone and sometimes nonexistent, so make sure you're handling network issues gracefully.

EDIT: The comment below would indicate this is actually a duplicate of [Access dev machine localhost via usb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524444/access-dev-machine-localhost-via-usb), although the original wording is pretty unclear.

Comment: @yoni Samlan: i have developed server side program on  apache tomcat.

Comment: @yoni Samlan: i have developed server side program on  apache tomcat. and i want to access it on android phone after deploying app. PC and phone are connected using usb cable. so im nt having access to ip of pc..in short, http://10.1.10.203(ip of pc):8080/myServlet request fails. do you have any idea regarding problem??

Comment: `adb forward` or test via wifi.

Comment: @yoni Salman : can you please tel me detail procedure to use adb forward or suggest me some tutorial ???

Comment: Guess you can't. that was an incorrect answer on the question that this is an exact duplicate of; consider adding a bounty to that question. Why can't you just use wifi?

Comment: ok..i totally new to this but how can i access my pc over wifi?? do i need public url(ip)??how to host my pc over internet??